# JSF2 + Richfaces: Ajax will render table only after second click

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm having trouble with Ajax render in JSF2. I have a command button in a table column that removes one item from the table. When i click the button, the action is executed and the item is removed from the database, however it is not removed from the table(view). When i click the second time, ajax render is executed and then the view is updated. I have no idea what could be causing this. At first i tought it could be the JSF spec issue 790, but my action is being fired. It is just the ajax render that is not being executed.

I'm using JSF 2.1.14 + RichFaces 4.2.3

Here's part of the code if you would like to help

```
    <a4j:outputPanel id="ajaxOutputPanel">
        <rich:panel id="panelOrgaoList">
            <div class="results" id="orgaoList">
                <h:outputText value="No results."
                    rendered="#{empty orgaoList.resultList}" />
                <h:form id="formTable">
                    <rich:dataTable id="orgaoTable" var="_orgao"
                        rowClasses="odd-row, even-row"
                        value="#{orgaoList.resultList}"
                        rendered="#{not empty orgaoList.resultList}" 
                        styleClass="stable">
                        <rich:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <ui:include src="layout/sort.xhtml">
                                    <ui:param name="entityList" value="#{orgaoList}" />
                                    <ui:param name="propertyLabel" value="Id" />
                                    <ui:param name="propertyPath" value="orgao.id" />
                                </ui:include>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{_orgao.id}" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <ui:include src="layout/sort.xhtml">
                                    <ui:param name="entityList" value="#{orgaoList}" />
                                    <ui:param name="propertyLabel" value="Name" />
                                    <ui:param name="propertyPath" value="orgao.name" />
                                </ui:include>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{_orgao.name}" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <ui:include src="layout/sort.xhtml">
                                    <ui:param name="entityList" value="#{orgaoList}" />
                                    <ui:param name="propertyLabel" value="Tel" />
                                    <ui:param name="propertyPath" value="orgao.tel" />
                                </ui:include>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{_orgao.tel}" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column styleClass="action">
                            <s:link view="/#{empty from ? 'Orgao' : from}.xhtml"
                                propagation="#{empty from ? 'none' : 'default'}"
                                id="orgaoViewId">
                                <f:param name="orgaoId" value="#{_orgao.idOrgao}" />
                                <h:graphicImage value="/img/view2.png" />
                            </s:link>
                         #{' '}
                        <s:link view="/OrgaoEdit.xhtml" propagation="none"
                                id="orgaoEdit" rendered="#{empty from}">
                                <h:graphicImage value="/img/edit2.png" />
                                <f:param name="orgaoId" value="#{_orgao.id}" />
                            </s:link>
                         #{' '}
                         <h:commandButton immediate="true" actionListener="#{orgaoList.remover(_orgao.id)}" image="/img/remove2.png">
                            <f:ajax render=":ajaxOutputPanel :formTable" />
                         </h:commandButton>
                        </rich:column>
                    </rich:dataTable>               
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </rich:panel>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
```

Thanks!

Comment: To avoid the obvious, is the `#{orgaoList.remover(_orgao.id)}` code removing the item from the list behind `#{orgaoList.resultList}` as well, or at least reloading the whole list from the DB? If unsure, post relevant code how you're managing the `resultList` property.

Comment: Hi BalusC, first of all thank you for the quick answer. The item is being removed and i checked that on the database. And when i refresh my page the view is updated and the item is removed from the table. I also debugged the bean code.

Comment: Ok, now i feel stupid. BalusC you were right. The problem was in the resultList. I'm using jboss seam(and i'm new to it) so i was using the EntityQuery class it provides to list the entities. After i removed the entity, this entity was still present in the resultList, so i called the refresh() method and worked. I just want to say that your answers, in many topics, helped me a lot. Thank you!